# Display:none not working. Tried suggested solutions to no success

Tags: css

I'm trying to get `display:none` to work for smaller screens. But I can't get it to work properly. The class disappears if I minimize the screen on my computer, but not when I check my phone.

I've tried the suggested solution on stack overflow of using `display:none!important;` to override the `display:block` in the info class, but that hasn't worked either. I've also tried taking out `display:block` from the info class but that didn't work. I don't think I can take out the `display:block` in `.tooltip` because then it messes with the layout.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
     <a href="#" class="info" data-tooltip-text="Header
Content."><img src="info_button.png"></img></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .info {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 18px;
     right: 30px;
     text-align: right;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     cursor: pointer;
     text-decoration: none;
     white-space:pre-wrap;
 }

 .tooltip {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 120%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #00DCFF;
    color: White;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
        }

.info:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(1);
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .info {
    display: none!important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's a number of reasons this might not be working - have you included the viewport meta tag for example?

Comment: Do you know the resolution of your phone? They can be surprisingly large

Comment: No I don't think I have included a viewport meta tag. I only have <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: My phone's resolution is 1136 x 640 pixels. But max-width:768px has worked in the past

Comment: This works fine in this jsFiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/u7guu35h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the **viewport meta tag** in the head of your main html file. It looks something like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Note that you can customize a few of the options you see in this tag.

Comment: Wow this worked! Amazing, thank you very much for the help!